# Typeorm groupBy get last row by orderBy another column

Tags: mysql, typeorm

I'm trouble with Typeorm to query the last row with duplicated column `quotationNO` and max value of `quotationVersion`

This is my table

[image]

this is the result that I want
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below would be one way,

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM   quotation t1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT quotationno, 
                          Max(quotationversion ) AS col1 
                   FROM   quotation
                   GROUP  BY quatationversion) t2 
               ON t1.quotationno = t2.quotationno 
                  AND t1.quotationversion = t2.col1;
```

If mySql version in 8.0, then you can also use anaytic function.

```
SELECT <reqcols> 
FROM   ( 
                SELECT   *, 
                         row_number() OVER (partition BY quotationno ORDER BY quotationversion DESC) AS rnk from quotation) a
WHERE  a.rnk=1;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have to query from only one table `quotation`

Comment: In first query there is self join on quotation, second query refers to only one table

Comment: SELECT sdsopheak_iserp.quotation.*
FROM   sdsopheak_iserp.quotation
       INNER JOIN (SELECT quotationNo,
                          Max(quotation.quotationVersion) AS col1
                   FROM sdsopheak_iserp.quotation
                   GROUP BY quotation.quotationVersion) t2
               ON quotation.quotationno = t2.quotationNo
                  AND quotation.quotationVersion = t2.quotationVersion;

Eorror: 
[42S22][1054] Unknown column 't2.quotationVersion' in 'on clause'

Comment: try this *SELECT 
t1.* FROM sdsopheak_iserp.quotation t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT quotationNo, Max(quotation.quotationVersion) AS col1 FROM sdsopheak_iserp.quotation GROUP BY quotation.quotationVersion) t2 ON t1.quotationno = t2.quotationNo AND t1.quotationVersion = t2.col1;*

Comment: Erro was syntax issue, quotationVersion was defined as col1 in subquery whereas in join condition it was refered by different name

Comment: The result is not correct I got a few rows and cannot get other single rows

Comment: Can you add sample data to the question for which you are not expecting results